# JTable print does not print header and footer

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I'm trying to print a JTable and I want a header and footer on each site. Here is my code (it is called, when i click the print button in my app):

```
final MessageFormat headerFormat = new MessageFormat("My Custom Table Header");
final MessageFormat footerFormat = new MessageFormat("- {0} -");
try
{
    this._table.print(PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, headerFormat, footerFormat);
}
catch (final Exception pe)
{
     //show message
}
return;
```

A printer dialog appears and i choose to print. The Table is printed perfectly, also over several pages, if it contains a lot of data. But there is no header or footer printed.

Any ideas, what's wrong with my code?

Thanks

Haferblues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your printer/driver does not support header/footers. I tried printing with above code to a pdf file and it works fine.

Comment: ok, thanks. I thought in 2012 it is not possible to have a printer/driver that doesn't support this basic feature. Obviously it is possible. Never could have figured out that.

Answer (score 0):

Above code works just fine. it is the printer( or settings) which is not printing header/footers.